# How would we allow users to create their own fields for forms in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

this might be a slightly broad question, but in essence, I'd like to allow my site's users to be able to add fields (text or char fields) to forms so that other users can fill them out. How exactly should I structure my models/forms/views to allow for this type of customization? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using metaclass:

```
from django.forms import BaseForm

fields = {
    'name': forms.CharField(max_length=50),
    'id': forms.IntegerField()
}

type('CustomForm', (BaseForm,), { 'base_fields': fields })
```

For a more comprehensive approach, use django-forms-builder:

http://django-forms-builder.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Mezzanine also supports this:

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/packages.html#module-mezzanine.forms

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How would you incorporate this into views and where will the information that these extra fields accept be saved?